# AWS SageMaker get logs from asynchronous inference endpoint and batch transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-sagemaker, inference

Is there a way to access the stdout from the asynchronous inference endpoint in AWS SageMaker?
I want to be able to view the output of the print commands that I use in the inference python script.
Also, which method can I use in order to retrieve the current progress from an inference session?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything sent to stdout/stderr would show up in CloudWatch.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/logging-cloudwatch.html

I am not sure what you mean by " Also, which method can I use in order to retrieve the current progress from an inference session"

Comment: thank you! I mean, how would you implement the mechanism to get the feedback from the inference process to notify the user?

Comment: You can use SNS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference.html